# Dissolving points produced by GeneratePointsAlongLines_management tool in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

The tool Generate Point Along lines generates points equal to the number of adjacent touching lines. For example, for 3 lines emerging from a point, the number of points generated would be 3.

How do I merge these points to a single point?

I have tried:

```
arcpy.GeneratePointsAlongLines_management (ORLinks, ORNodes, "DISTANCE", Distance='5000 meters', Include_End_Points='END_POINTS')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("ORNodes", "ORNodes")
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis ('ORNodes', 'ORNodes', temp3, "","","INTERSECT")
```

but, this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Felix, using the `Delete Identical` tool worked.

```
arcpy.DeleteIdentical_management (ORNodes, ["Shape"])
```